# Replace empty column by some string in Oracle Materialized view

Tags: oracle, conditional-operator, materialized-views

I have to create a materialized view based on data:-

```
ID   Class_Code   Student_Name
1     1011         Jatin
2     1012         Pual
3                  Patrick
4     1014         Liaba
5                   Noah
```

and i want a materialized view to return

```
 ID   Class_Code  Student_Name
 1     1011        Jatin
 2     1012        Pual
 3     Not Enrolled Patrick
 4     1014         Liaba
 5     Not Enrolled Noah
```

Yes i did some research on google and did not get any thing. CASE WHEN statements return weird results. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is much complexed. You may try this below simple query -

```
SELECT ID, NVL(Class_Code, 'Not Enrolled') Class_Code, Student_Name
  FROM YOUR_MV;
```

Comment: If this does not offend you. Please refer me some good resource that help me write such practical queries. I am complete dumb.

Comment: You may definitely try hackerrank then.

Comment: hackerrank hire developers. i need learning resource

Comment: Just log in for developers and opt for the SQL course. There are ample questions for practice.

Comment: Stay blessed Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `NVL`:

```
NVL(class_code, 'Not Enrolled')
```

This way, whenever the value for the column `CLASS_CODE` is `NULL`, it will populate the void with a "Not Enrolled".